# Bootstrap table with Tooltip text not wrapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, tooltip

I have a tooltip is in responsive table. However, I realised the text inside the tooltip is not wrapping it nicely in mobile view only.

Please see example here: http://www.bootply.com/4fFLE90WAl#
You need to render the mobile view and mouseover and see the issue

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your **CSS**

```
.tooltip-inner  {

    white-space:pre; /* you can also try white-space: normal; */
    max-width:none;

}
```

And it will work like a charm. They key attribute here is `white-space`. Read more about it **[here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)**

Comment: Hi Hristo, I resolved it by adding this line "data-container="body". Is it ok or is using white-space a better choice?

Comment: Hey! Your workaround is really great because you are not overriding anything, but you are making the tweak dependent on bootstrap.Although this is not a bad thing, it may go wrong because the behavior of the rule can change in future versions of bootstrap (it has happened before with other settings) and you may have to find a way to fix it again. 

The choice is up to you. Both options work well for now.

Comment: Thanks @Hristo for the confirmation! :)

Answer (score 4):

I resolved it by adding this line "data-container="body"

So it looks like that now

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="this paragraph is too long and the text does not wrap around in mobile view, i don't know why this is happening. please help">Hover over me</a>
```

Is it ok? Or the solution provided by Hristo is a better one?

Comment: I done this with jQuery: $("a[title]").each(function () {        $(this).attr('data-container', 'body'); });. Works great!

Answer (score 3):

```
![.tooltip-inner{white-space:normal;}][1]
```

[image]